# Bing - Is there a NCR site for it?

Tags: google, search-engine, bing

Just like Google having an [NCR (No Country Redirect) URL](http://www.google.com/ncr), does Bing have one?

Basically, I am looking for a site URL which will take me to the US - English site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at Bing's [Search Worldwide](http://www.bing.com/worldwide.aspx) page.

US-English page is [here](http://www.bing.com/?scope=web&setmkt=en-US&setlang=SET_NULL&uid=A9F55FA1&FORM=W5WA).